# Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration for react

Tags: json, reactjs, ubuntu-16.04, webpack-2

Im currently doing TylerMcginnes React Fundamentals course , while I am relatively new to front end I wish to learn to the current accepted style so am linting with eslint airbnb config and prettier, however since i changed from Tyler's coding a.k.a(no imports, all requires, no es6 functionality) i have got this "Field "browser" doesnt contain a valid alias configuration error and it says that my index.jsx doesnt exist in the exact location that it is??

My Env is Ubuntu 16.04

Attached is my bash error screen, file tree,package.json and webpack.config anyone who can lend some assistance and put me out of my 6 hours of searching and atemping would be greatly appreciated

[image: Bash Error]

[image: Package.Json]

[image: webpack.config.js]

[image: File Tree]

I have looked at every other answer regarding this issue and most seem to be typo's, it would drive me crazy if I'm so blind i couldn't see it after the time I've spent looking

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your entry value in your webpack.config.js should just be ./app/index.jsx